# Indexing needs to be sped up

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table with the following details:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `seenDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00',
  `corrected_test` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `corrected_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `unable_to_correct` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `fk_zone_for_correction` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sightinguid`),
  KEY `corrected_test` (`corrected_test`),
  KEY `idx_seenDate` (`seenDate`),
  KEY `idx_corrected_test_seenDate` (`corrected_test`,`seenDate`),
  KEY `zone_for_correction_fk_idx` (`fk_zone_for_correction`),
  KEY `idx_corrected_test_zone` (`fk_zone_for_correction`,`corrected_test`,`seenDate`),
  CONSTRAINT `zone_for_correction_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_zone_for_correction`) REFERENCES `zone_test` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am then using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    test
WHERE
    fk_zone_for_correction = 1
        AND (unable_to_correct = 0
        OR unable_to_correct IS NULL)
        AND (corrected_test = ''
        OR corrected_test IS NULL)
        AND (last_accessed_timestamp IS NULL
        OR last_accessed_timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE))
        ORDER BY seenDate ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Here is a screenshot of the optimiser - the `ORDER BY` is slowing things down, and in my opinion seems to be indexed properly, and the correct index (`idx_corrected_test_zone`) is being selected.  What can be done to improve it?

[image]

Comment: Please do not cross-post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192833/speed-up-query-when-seemingly-correct-index-is-being-used

Comment: Please show us the text version of `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no INDEX that will help much.

This *might* help:

```
INDEX(fk_zone_for_correction, seenDate)
```

Both columns can perhaps be used -- the first for filtering, the second for avoiding having to sort.  But, it could backfire if it can't find the `1` row quickly.

The killer is `OR`.  If you could avoid ever populating any of those 3 columns with `NULL`, then this might be better:

```
INDEX(fk_zone_for_correction, unable_to_correct, corrected_test, last_accessed_timestamp)
-- the range thing needs to be last
-- this index would do the filtering, but fail to help with `ORDER` and `LIMIT`.
```

Even though it is using `idx_corrected_test_zone`, it is probably not using more than the first two columns -- because of `OR`.

You have two cases of redundant indexes.  For example, the first of these is the *left* part of the second; so the first is redundant and can be `DROPped`:

```
KEY `corrected_test`              (`corrected_test`),
KEY `idx_corrected_test_seenDate` (`corrected_test`,`seenDate`),
```